# Swift 3 button disappears from tableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a tableView that has (for now) only a button in each cell.

I hard coded the number of rows to be 100:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}
```

And this is my cellForRowAt function that creates the button and is suppose to properly place it in each cell:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    let row = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let btn = UIButton(type:(UIButtonType.custom)) as UIButton
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    btn.setTitle("(read more)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    btn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 10)
    btn.frame = CGRect(x:300, y:row.bounds.height, width:70, height:20)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonPressed:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    btn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.contentView.addSubview(btn)

    return cell
}
```

So this places the buttons in each cell, but when I click on the cell, the associated button disappears or when i scroll down, most of the first few buttons are gone when I scroll back up. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This example maybe will help you:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var tableView: UITableView!

fileprivate let numberOfItems = 100

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.contentInset.top = 44
}

@objc fileprivate func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    print("tag: \(sender.tag)")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfItems
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let accessory = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 20))
    accessory.backgroundColor = .black
    accessory.setTitle("Read more", for: .normal)
    accessory.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
    accessory.tag = indexPath.row
    accessory.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.accessoryView = accessory

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: I basically have the same thing, expect for cell.accessoryView = accessory.. I have cell.contentView.addSubview(btw) instead. When substituting what you put vs what I put it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Never mind I copy pasted your code and it seemed to work...Probably something stupid i missed.

Answer (score 0):

you must create a cell everytime in `cellForRowAt` rather get the cell from dequeue and draw your content again. Creating a cell again and again is not an good idea. Finding own mistake and solving will another curve of learning.

l

```
et cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell") // should not do

let row = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) // can use it.
```

both line together should not use.